# Beginner: How to send Progress bar Content?

Tags: android, bluetooth, seekbar

I have the following problem.
I added a few buttons to the app bluetoothChat, witch send an specific text by clicking on them. For doing so I entered the name of the programm with should be started by clicking the button in the onClick propertie. e.g: onClick = halloClick.

I added this to the code:

```
    public void halloClick(View view) {
     sendMessage("Hallo");
 }
```

So far it does its job. Everytime I push the button "Hallo" is sent.

Now I added a button and a seekbar. I want the Value of the seekbar sent out everytime I push the button. So i set the onClick of the button to "sendValue" and added the following Code witch I found on the Internet:

```
     public void sendValue(View view) {
    sendMessage(seekBar1.getProgress ());
    }
```

Eclipse Displays the Error: seekBar1 cannot be resolved.

Where is my Mistake?
In the Layout the seekbar is realized in this way:

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"/>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you created abstract object of seekbar in you app by doing as below,

Answer (score 0):

have you created abstract object of seekbar in you app by doing as below,

```
public void sendValue(View view) {
     Seekbar seekBar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
     sendMessage(seekBar1.getProgress ());
}
```